# WebAPI global exception handler

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, asp.net-web-api

There is a global exception handler in our WebAPI application that looks like the following:

```
public class ApiExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public async Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        var exceptionType = context.Exception.GetType();

        if (exceptionType == typeof(ResourceNotFoundException))
        {
            context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(
                context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, context.Exception.Message));
        }

        else if (exceptionType == typeof(UserNotFoundException))
        {
            context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(
                context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, context.Exception.Message));
        }

        else if (exceptionType == typeof(UserAlreadyExistsExeption))
        {
            context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(
                context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, context.Exception.Message));
        }

        ...

        else
        {
            context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(
                context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "An unexpected error occured"));
        }
    }
}
```

And each exception has the following form:

```
public class UserAlreadyExistsExeption: Exception
{
    public UserAlreadyExistsExeption()
    {
    }

    public UserAlreadyExistsExeption(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }

    public UserAlreadyExistsExeption(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner)
    {

    }
}
```

And can be thrown in the code like the following:

```
//If user exists
throw new UserAlreadyExistsExeption("User already exists");
```

I was thinking of making all our custom exceptions implement a `IHasHttpErrorCode` so each one has its own `HttpErrorCode` - usage like the following:

Interface:

```
public interface IHasHttpErrorCode
{
    HttpStatusCode GetHttpStatusCode();
}
```

Exception:

```
public class UserAlreadyExistsExeption: Exception, IHasHttpErrorCode
{
    public UserAlreadyExistsExeption()
    {
    }

    public UserAlreadyExistsExeption(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }

    public UserAlreadyExistsExeption(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner)
    {

    }

    public HttpStatusCode GetHttpStatusCode() {
        return HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
    }
}
```

Global Error Handler:

```
public class ApiExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public async Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        var exceptionType = context.Exception as IHasHttpErrorCode;


        if (customException != null) { 
            context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(
                context.Request.CreateResponse(customException.GetHttpStatusCode(), context.Exception.Message));
        } 
        else
        {
            context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(
                context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "An unexpected error occured"));
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a valid approach to improve the existing code? Is there anything else I should look to improve?

Comment: I would personally go even further and make common abstract base to force you to implement the status code.

Comment: @Heslacher Whoops I'll fix that now.

Comment: @firda Is that much different from an interface? What would it look like?

Comment: @TomSelleck the only difference is that you can forget to add the interface, but cannot forget to implement the (abstract) status code _if_ you derive all your exceptions from common abstract base... which you can of course forget as well, but having one common base exception for a library / group of objects has another advantages (catching base) and therefore solves two things at once (and maybe you already have the common base exception).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the interface is definitely an improvement, but what I lack in your code is **common base exception**, something like `ServerException` that could be used to distinguish other exceptions (e.g. `IndexOutOfRangeException` or whatever) from *your* exceptions (useful for catching).

That common base could be made `abstract` to force you to define `HttpStatusCode`

```
public abstract class ServerException: Exception {
//  standard constructors...
    public abstract HttpStatusCode GetHttpStatusCode();
}
```

Now, if you derive any custom exception from this (as you should, maybe creating some other abstract derived exceptions for some groups of problems), then you have to `override` (define) the code (or it would have to remain `abstract` and you won't be able to `throw` it).

```
public class UserAlreadyExistsExeption: ServerException {
//  again standard .ctors
    override public HttpStatusCode GetHttpStatusCode() => HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
}
```

Alternative would be to use public get-only property and initialize it in the constructor, maybe even having one exception type (and use `try-catch-when`), but I am not sure that can be used in your code (would require perfect 1-to-1 match between exception types and status codes).

## Make message default

```
public class UserAlreadyExistsExeption: Exception, IHasHttpErrorCode
{
    public UserAlreadyExistsExeption(): base("User already exists") {}
}
```

and

```
throw new UserAlreadyExistsExeption();
```

instead of

```
throw new UserAlreadyExistsExeption("User already exists");
```

Maybe even handling localization in the default constructor, if needed.